# Confusing gcc extern symbol linker issue using static libraries

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have an app built using CMake that includes two static libs, called libA and libB.

Static libA has a function defined:

```
void onData(char *msg) __attribute__((used));

void onData(char *msg) {
    printf("test: %s\n", msg);
}
```

Static lib B has the following in `myfunc.c`:

```
extern void onData(char *msg);

void myfunc() {
    onData("hello");
}
```

The function `myfunc` is called by the main app, and I expect to see `test: hello` in stdout.

Actually the app fails to link with:

```
libB.a(myfunc.c.o): In function `myfunc':
myfunc.c:10: undefined reference to `onData'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I assumed this was to do with libA failing to include the `onData` symbol (since it's not being used by libA), hence the attempt to fix this with `__attribute__((used))`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Now... if I add some code in another function (**within libA**), for example:

```
extern void onData(char *msg);

int main() {
    printf("Location of onData: %p", onData);
}
```

Then the app links fine. So it is something to do with inclusion/exclusion of the code by gcc, but `objdump` and `nm` show the function is included in all scenarios!

```
$ nm libA.a
ondata.c:
0000000000000000 T onData
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: I think the interesting part is what's in your makefile, i.e. how does the code get built

Comment: Please show us how you compile and build both libraries and the application.